# shell script - while condition check range failing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, wildcard

I just started shell scripting and for test purposes I'm trying to create scripts for my personal use.
I have a home fileserver that I sync from and to sometimes and I'm trying to create an interactive script so i can make the task of mp3 syncing easier.

Here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
##############################################
############    MP3 SYNC SCRIPT ##############
##############################################
#### REV: 01 20/07/2015
#### Author: Marcio Ribeiro

echo -e "Sincronizar do storage para o note ( escolha 01 ) ou do note para storage ( escolha 02 ): \n 01 Destino final Note: \n 02 Destino final Storage:"
read  DESTINO
DESTINO_CK=[0]-[12]

    while [ $DESTINO != $DESTINO_CK ] ; do

    read -p "Por favor escolha entre 01 ou 02:" DESTINO
done

echo -e "Digite a letra inicial da banda que deseja utilizar na sincronização em CAPS"
read  LETRA
LETRACK={AZ}

    while [ "$LETRA" != $LETRACK ]; do

    read -p "Digite a letra inicial da banda que deseja utilizar na sincronização em CAP:" LETRA
done

LEFT="/storage/Marcio/Mp3/${LETRA}/"
RIGHT="/data/mp3/${LETRA}/"

if [ $DESTINO = "01" ]; then
    echo -e "`rsync -rvz ${LEFT} ${RIGHT}`; \n `ls -lha ${RIGHT}`"
else
    echo -e "`rsync -rvz ${RIGHT} ${LEFT}`; \n `ls -lha ${LEFT}`"

  fi
```

I got the basics working now I'm trying to limit the user interaction to what I really want but I'm failing.
Basically on the first user prompt I only want to accept 01 or 02 as input and on the second user prompt only a capital single letter.
Anyone have a clue why I'm failing on something so simple?

Comment: `=` and `!=` do exact matching, not pattern matching.

Comment: @Barmar: Unless in `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: `echo -e "$(cmd)"` is an anti-pattern.  Just execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, it's not a pretty code or the best logic but it works :

```
!/bin/bash
##############################################
############    MP3 SYNC SCRIPT ##############
##############################################
#### REV: 01 20/07/2015
#### Author: Marcio Ribeiro

echo -e "Sincronizar do storage para o note ( escolha 1 ) ou do note para storage ( escolha 2 ): \n 1: Destino final Note \n 2: Destino final Storage"
read  DESTINO
            until [ "$DESTINO" = "1" ] || [ "$DESTINO" = "2" ];
do
            read -p "Por favor escolha entre 1 ou 2:" DESTINO
done
####
echo -e "Digite a letra inicial da banda que deseja utilizar na sincronização em CAPS"
read  LETRA
LETRA_CK='[A-Z]'

            while [[ "$LETRA" != $LETRA_CK ]];
do
            read -p "Digite a letra inicial da banda que deseja utilizar na sincronização em CAPS:" LETRA
done
####
LEFT="/storage/Marcio/Mp3/${LETRA}/"
RIGHT="/data/mp3/${LETRA}/"

    if [ $DESTINO = "01" ]; then
            echo -e "`rsync -rvz ${LEFT} ${RIGHT}`; \n `ls -lha ${RIGHT}`"
else
            echo -e "`rsync -rvz ${RIGHT} ${LEFT}`; \n `ls -lha ${LEFT}`"

fi
```

Any ideas for improvement are welcome.